# Dapper "Procedure or function sp_XXXX has too many arguments specified."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dapper, micro-orm

I am using Dapper's DynamicParamters object with the template argument to generate arguments with my entities.  After I make my call to my stored procedure I am getting the following error "Procedure or function sp_MemberSave has too many arguments specified.".  I do have extra properties on some of my entities for business logic, etc.  Is there a way to make sure dapper only passes parameters that are actual parameters for the stored procedure?  It seems like Dapper would read the stored procedure first and then set the parameters, that way it would only use the ones that are correct.  How can I limit the parameters using the template capabilities?

Comment: Are you passing your object (an instance of your class) as the parameter to the stored procedure?

Comment: I am calling DynamicParameters(entity) where entity is one of my entities.  My thoughts were that this would generate the Parameters collection by reading the entity and generating the Parameters collection.  I also thought it would ignore any parameters that aren't actual stored prcoedure parameters.  Is this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try creating an anonymous type of the appropriate parameters from your object... If your class has A, B, C, and D, and you only need A and B:

```
DynamicParameters(new { A = entity.A, B = entity.B });
```

Comment: I was hoping that I didn't have to do it that way as there are alot of parameters.  Alot.

Comment: I understand. We wrote a wrapper for Dapper at my company that has some neat features... one of which is adding a [NotParameter] attribute that allows the wrapper to ignore properties/fields.

Comment: I was reviewing their code to find a place to filter parameters as they are added, but the section that performs the adding seemed a little hard to follow:-).

Comment: There's a lot of ExpressionTrees and reflection used to create methods on the fly in Dapper... Properly, mind you.

Comment: Right.  I think I found where it generates the parameters, trying to translate it.  Though, it is interesting.

Comment: Out of sheer frustration, I think I will have to create the anonymous type.  Thank you guys for all of the help.

Comment: Okay, David H.  When your team created the [NoParameter] attribute, did you create an extension method that would take convert the entity to a parameter list using reflection.  If this is the case, my only question would be did you notice any performance hits using reflection?

Comment: We created an intermediary that would create an anonymous type and map it... And there's a hit initially but we compiled the method and cached it to make future use nearly as fast as a compile-time method.

Comment: @Haney is it possible that you can share the code that you guys have written as a wrapper for dapper with [NotParameter]. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can I be very clear on the scenario here? if you just pass the entity (rather than the `DynamicParameters`) it *does* do this analysis; i.e. `conn.Execute("some sql", someEntity);` - it will then only add the members of `someEntity` that it can see are used in the SQL. There may be *some* false positives, as it doesn't perform full lexical SQL analysis, so a parameter in comments, i.e.:

```
-- removed by Fred: where row.Date < @StartDate
```

will still be included (so in the example above, the member `StartDate` would be eligible, even though it probably isn't *actually* needed).

However; `DynamicParameters` currently trusts the custom implementation. I suppose we *could* move the parameter analysis check to after this point, but I'd prefer to understand the full scenario first.

Comment: "... it does do this analysis" - does it do the analysis for stored procedures (which is what the OP's using)?

Comment: @Joe if the command-type says stored procedure, then no: it does not. However, it is also possible to use stored procedures via the text command-type (via `exec`) - I see this fairly often - hence the desire to see a very clear example. But one thing is for certain: dapper will never attempt to "read the stored procedure first"